# Emit current document name and line number from XSL/XPath

Tags: .net, xslt, xpath

Is there a way to emit the uri of the document currently being processed (which may or may not have been loaded with a document() function call) and preferably the line number?

Basically I have a situation in my XSL where there could potentially be an error so I am using

```
<xsl:message terminate="yes">...</xsl:message>
```

It would be nice if the message could include the location of the error in the source xml document.

Currently I am using the built-in .NET XSL engine, although I may have to switch to using saxon for another issue.

Answer (score 0):

With an XSLT 2.0 processor you can use `base-uri(.)` for the URI. Saxon has an extension http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/line-number for the line number.

With XSLT 1.0 I think to have access to the input URI you have to define a parameter and pass the value in from your application.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing very useful in the XSLT 1.0 specification.

The 2.0 spec has base-uri() and document-uri(). They mean slightly different things: the document-uri is a URI that can be used to load the document using doc() (which might be unrelated to the actual location of the document because of URIResolvers and EntityResolvers), while the base-uri() applies to each element node, and is the URI used to resolve relative URI references (which might be different from the document location because of xml:base attributes and external entity boundaries).

Saxon provides saxon:system-id() which is intended to be the URI of the actual file that a particular element was loaded from, and saxon:line-number() which is the line number of that element in that source file. This depends on retaining line number information when you build the document: option -l on the command line. I don't think there is anything similar in the Microsoft processor.